# How to get rid of "must use restructuring props" assignment

Tags: reactjs

I am calling in the method in the following way:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.updateFoo({a: false,b : false, c: false,d : true, e: true });
    }
```

And I get a warning "Must use destructuring props assignment".

Answer (score 3):

By default rule is set to always enforce destructuring assignment.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { updateFoo } = this.props
    updateFoo({a: false,b : false, c: false,d : true, e: true });
}
```

This should do the trick, for more details see [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md)